# SQL join misses data from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

Purchases:

```
PUR#   EID PID  CID          QTY  PTIME     TOTAL_PRICE
--------------------------------------------------------
100001 e01 p002 c001          1 12-AUG-17      211.65
100002 e01 p003 c001          1 20-SEP-17       118.4
100003 e02 p004 c002          5 08-OCT-17        4.95
100005 e04 p007 c004          1 15-OCT-17       119.2
100006 e03 p008 c001          1 12-OCT-17       349.3
100007 e03 p006 c003          2 10-SEP-17       35.91
```

Products

```
PID  NAME                   QOH | QOH_THRESHOLD | ORIGINAL_PRICE   DISCNT_RATE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
p001 stapler                 60            20           9.99          .1
p002 TV                       6             5            249         .15
p003 camera                  20             5            148          .2
p004 pencil                 100            10            .99           0
p005 chair                   10             8          12.98          .3
```

I have to find

What I am able to find is people who purchases just in date and give the count but I AM NOT ABLE TO SHOW THE PRODUCT COUNT AS 0 FOR THOSE WHO DINT PURCHASED ANYTHING IN date.
I want the output to show for all products

My Query:

```
select count(qty) as "noc", pd.pid, pd.name 
from purchases p 
  inner join products pd on pd.pid = p.pid 
where (to_char(p.ptime, 'Mon-YYYY')='Oct-2017' 
  AND p.qty =p.qty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default inner joins only output rows that have a match. To keep rows without a match, you need a [left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) in this case:

```
SELECT COUNT(qty) AS noc, PD.pid, PD.name
FROM   products PD LEFT JOIN purchases P
ON     (PD.pid = P.pid AND P.ptime = 'OCT-17')
GROUP  BY PD.pid, PD.name
ORDER  BY noc DESC;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f8e5f/15.

Further reading: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).